# the conflict between running spark-sql and hive-on-spark

Tags: apache-spark, hive

according to the official document, when one want to running hive using the spark engine, he need to rebuild spark without hive.but, when I running spark-sql in the same environment ,I got an error:that I must rebuild the spark with -Phive .

As a workaround,i down spark-hive-thiftserver_2.11-2.2.1.jar and spark-hive-_2.11-2.0.0.jar  from maven repository and put them in the `${SPARK_HOME}/jars/` .but this approach seems does not work.

thanks

Comment: Added code block

Comment: the reason why the approach doesn't work is that there are many version mismatch problems between the download spark-hive*.jar and the spark version of the hive-on-spark environment.  
when  I set up the hive-on-spark environment .I use spark-2.0.0,hive-2.3.1,hadoop-2.6.5. I manually rebuilt the spark-2.0.0-without-hive-hadoop2.6.5 package in advance.so definitely when I want to run spark-sql, I cannot find a suitable spark-hive jar for this environment.
my english is poor.i hope I have expressed the issue clearly. Thanks.